# Python how to randomly pick 2 randoms between 1 and 6

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I was trying to make this code 
and I prints out 3 lines of numbers 1 - 6 in random order which is good. But is there any way to make it print pairs of numbers between 1 and 6 instead of just 6 numbers randomised?
Example: It currently prints:

```
 [1, 6, 5, 3, 4, 2]
```

Desired print:

```
[1, 6]
[5, 3]
[4, 2]
```

code:

```
@bot.command()
async def teams(ctx, players):
    await ctx.send("Ido - 1: Yona - 2: Noam - 3: Gil - 4: Liel - 5: Yuval - 6:")
    await ctx.send('Calculating...')
    from random import shuffle
    sequence1 = [i for i in range(1, int(players)+1)]
    shuffle(sequence1)
    await ctx.send(sequence1)

    sequence2 = [i for i in range(1, int(players)+1)]
    shuffle(sequence2)
    await ctx.send(sequence2)

    sequence3 = [i for i in range(1, int(players) + 1)]
    shuffle(sequence3)
    await ctx.send(sequence3)
```

Comment: What do you want to happen if the list has an odd length, e.g. 7 players?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Your posted code defines a function and quits, as there is no main program, and no other end to your communication line.  You have undefined symbols.  Finally, there is no `print` or other viable output command; perhaps it's behind one of those undefined symbols?

Comment: Also, "chunking" a list (which is what I suspect you want to do), is well covered in many places on line, including this site.  Perhaps you can find it with that search term.

Comment: @Prune The `command` decorator registers a callback for the `discord.py` bot to invoke when it sees a command invocation in the discord chat.  There isn't really any context you're missing.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh to makes pair from 1-7. and also you're correct.

Comment: @Prune This is using discord.py so it has the discord.py commands such as ctx.send, the command decorator, etc.

Comment: @ido2103 You can't make pairs from 1-7 because you would have one left over.  Are your inputs always going to be even, do you want one of the other values to appear in two groups, should that one be by itself, do you want to exclude it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using list comprehension this will also handle uneven lists by creating a singular group at the end.

```
l = [1, 6, 5, 3, 4, 2]
n = 2
lst = [l[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(l), n)]
for i in lst:
    print(i)

[1, 6]
[5, 3]
[4, 2]
```

Comment: Tysm that's exactly what i wanted :)